# Java : Method overriding in return statement

Tags: java

I have this code which is not being overridden at its return statement. And 20 is output, Why is that happening? Any Explanation about this would be helpful.

```
class Rectangle {
    public int area(int length, int width){
        return length*width;
    }
}

class Square extends Rectangle{
    public int area(long length, long width){
        return (int) Math.pow(length, 2);
    }
}
public class JavaApplication36 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Square r = new Square();
        System.out.println(r.area(5, 4));
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn’t override the method because one uses ints and one uses longs. Your values are ints. Change the method signature to use ints.

Answer (score 2):

Because Square area doesn't override Rectangle area. Their signatures are different. The area method types are different. Add @override above Square area method and you will no longer be able to compile, but will get an error telling you that you aren't overriding the method.